# Android does not Toast after successful POST

Tags: android, json, grails, android-intent, toast

I am sending data from an android client to a grails backend. I want two things to happen when data is successfully posted:

1. A toast with some of the params I have posted(In this case I want
   only name)
2. An intent to open another activity.

However with my code, the parameters are posted successfully to the db but the toast and the intent do not happen.

Here is my code:

```
 */
    private void registerUser(final String chname, final String chdesc, final String patientID) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                Configs.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {
                        // User successfully stored in MySQL
                        // Now store the user in sqlite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String chname = user.getString("name");
                        String chdesc = user.getString("description");
                        String patientID = user.getString("patient");



                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User successfully registered.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Launch login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(AddChronics.this,
                                ChronicsFragment.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {

                        // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                        // message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to activity_register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", chname);
                params.put("description", chdesc);
                params.put("patient", patientID);

                params.put("action", "chronicAdd");

                return params;


            }


        };



        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }
```

Note: The API works just fine. I have checked and the params are successfully saved to the db.

Comment: Place a Toast in that catch block.

Comment: Thanks!!! I did that it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, the only thing that might prevent the intent and toast from happening is if your code gets cought by an excepetion here:

```
    catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Caused by one of these guys:

```
     String uid = jObj.getString("uid");
     JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
```

Did you check that?

Comment: I removed the uid and placed the toast and the intent inside the catch block rather than in the try block. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using activity context instead of applicationContext?

Comment: this online should be in comment.

Comment: no that doesn't work. I found the solution as I have explained above. Thanks.